# Ember error while creating dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Apologies if this has already been asked and I couldn't figure that out.

I am attempting to link an Ember dynamic Route with a Template. It's not working. The error for the below code is `Error while processing route: favorite undefined is not a function`

The idea is that the main page should show a list of favorites that are returned via Ajax. Each favorite should have a link. The user clicks a link and the favorite is injected into the relevant template on the same page.

The main page is working correctly. With the code below, the links are currently showing `index.html/#/12345ab` where 12345ab is the `product_id`.

**HTML Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="favorites">
{{#each favorite in arrangedContent}}
    <div class="productBox">
        {{#link-to 'favorite' favorite.product_id}}
            <img {{bind-attr src=favorite.product_image}} />
        {{/link-to}}
    </div>
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="favorite">
    <h2>{{product_name}}</h2>
    <img {{bind-attr src=product_image}} />
</script>
```

**Router code:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('favorites', { path: '/'});
    this.resource('favorite', { path: ':product_id' });
});

App.FavoritesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.$.ajax({
            //this returns correctly
        }).then(function(data) {
            return data.favorites;
        });
    }
});

App.FavoriteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Favorites.findBy('product_id', params.product_id);
    }
});
```

**Update:**

The answer below gives the following code, but if the user goes directly to the page via the URL or a straight refresh, it fails due to the fact that the `favorites` model is not resolved yet. Exact error is: `Cannot read property 'findBy' of undefined`

```
App.FavoriteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.modelFor('favorites').findBy('product_id', params.product_id);
    }
});
```

**Update 2:**
Entire Router code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('favorites', { path: '/'});
    this.resource('favorite', { path: ':product_id' });
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: 'MY_URL',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback'
            }).then(function(data) {
                resolve(data.favorites);
            });
        });
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        return this.controllerFor('favorites').set('model', model);
    }
});

App.FavoriteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(
        return this.controllerFor('favorites').get('model').findBy('product_id', params.product_id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the Ember IRC channel, this is the working code. In essence, it creates an Index template for both the `favorites` and the `favorite` template to render into. Then the `favorite` route can access it's parent route `favorites` and yet still render into the same template area.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="favorites">
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="favorites/index">
{{#each favorite in arrangedContent}}
    <div class="productBox">
        {{#link-to 'favorite' favorite.product_id}}
            <img {{bind-attr src=favorite.product_image}} />
        {{/link-to}}
    </div>
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="favorite">
    <h2>{{product_name}}</h2>
    <img {{bind-attr src=product_image}} />
</script>
```

**Router.js**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('favorites', { path: '/'}, function () {
      this.resource('favorite', { path: ':product_id' });
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
    this.replace('favorites');
  }
});

App.FavoritesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: 'MY_URL',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback'
            }).then(function(data) {
                resolve(data.favorites);
            });
        });
    }
});

App.FavoriteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
     return this.modelFor('favorites').findBy('product_id', params.product_id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, you want to find the model from the parent route.  You can do it likes so:

```
App.FavoriteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
   this.modelFor('favorites').arrangedContent.findBy('product_id', params.product_id);
 }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that your promise from the parent route isn't getting resolved correctly.  You're returning a promise but the result of that promise isn't getting resolved i.e. (return data.favorites) is not resolving the promise.

Update it to:

```
App.FavoritesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Ember.$.ajax('yourURL').then(
          function(data){
            resolve(data.favorites); 
        });
    });    
  }
});
```

Also incorporate the initial feedback from this answer.  I have a working JSBin going against an actual endpoint to show it works: http://jsbin.com/boloya/3/edit

P.S.  Look out for params.product_id, that comes in as a string.  You made need to cast it to the required type in order for the findBy to work correctly.

P.S.S. I should also add, Ember.$.ajax returns a promise, but you want the model to be data.favorites which is the need for the outer promise.  If you just returned Ember.$.ajax and accessed everything via model.favorites you wouldn't need it.

Comment: That (namely `modelFor`) was what I have been looking for for a long time. The working code ended up being `return this.modelFor('favorites').findBy('product_id', params.product_id);` For some reason it didn't like the `arrangedContent` part and I needed to return the whole thing. Thanks.

Comment: One further question. The model errors out when arriving at the page via URL (instead of the `link-to`). The error is `can't read findBy of undefined` which means it's not finding the `favorites` model when not coming from a link from the favorites page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it's because your designating them as resources vs routes.  Try switching them to nested routes.

Comment: I updated the update to include the `App.Router.map`. It's still giving the same error, `can't read findBy of undefined`. I have also tried replacing the `route` part with `resource`.

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is...Mine was working because the parent route's model was resolved immediately.  It all comes down to Promises...Promises, lol.  I'll modify my answer to reflect the problem correctly.

Comment: Hmmm. Still giving the same error. I've added the entire Router code to Update #2. Couple of thoughts: 1) Is the JSONP interfering? 2) The product_id is a string (mixed numbers and letters), is that a problem for Ember? 3) The two routes are NOT nested (they were originally but I changed that for other reasons (namely templating), is that messing with things?

Comment: The id CAN be a string, I casted to an int because otherwise the comparison would fail.  Ember's params are strings so you'll be fine.  Can you create a JS Bin with your code and your end-point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65534/discussion-between-josh-and-wojciech-wieronski).

Answer (score 0):

Your routes need to be [nested](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources) for a child resource to have access to a parent via `#modelFor`. However, if your UI isn't nested, your routes probably shouldn't be, since nesting routes also wires up a corresponding view hierarchy.

You could always define the model for the `favorite` route in terms of a subset of the data returned by your ajax call:

```
//routes/favorite.js
model: function() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/favorites').then(function(favorites) {
      return favorites.findBy('id', params.product_id');
    });
}
```

but then, the top-level `.getJSON('/favorites`)`call would be made multiple times, every time the user enters`/favorites`, and every time he enters`/favorites/:id`.

Instead, you can have the application set up the `FavoritesController` once upon entry. That way you can share data, but `favorite` doesn't have to be a child route of `favorites`. It might look something this:

```
//routes/application.js
model: function() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/favorites');
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.controllerFor('favorites').set('model', model);
}
```

and

```
//routes/favorite.js
model: function(params) {
  return this.controllerFor('favorites').find('id', params.id);
}
```

That way, the JSON is only loaded once, `ApplicationRouter` is wiring up your `FavoritesController` for you, and the data is shared with the `favorite` resource.

Comment: That all makes sense. For the implementation of the last section, the `FavoriteRoute`. It's returning `undefined`. The `this.controllerFor('favorites')` returns the right object (at least, it has a method called `model` that has the right data). Find and findBy don't return anything however.

Comment: is it an array? try `.get('model')` maybe?

Comment: So that got the model from the controller. It works great if following a link. If you refresh the page though, the code pulls up the `favorites` controller just fine (and it has the model sub-object with all the data), but `get('model')` returns empty. I don't understand... See Update #2 for the current code.

Comment: SO isn't really the place for this type of discussion. Try jumping into the #ember channel on IRC.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help.